# Independent and dependent initial conditions

Tags: passive-networks, transient, state-space

Consider the RLC circuit below.
[image]

In fact, it is a normalized filter with Butterworth approximation of 3rd order.

Now suppose that for some reason I am interested in the time domain formulation.
Using KCL and KVL I ended up with these state equations:

\begin{gather}
\frac{\mathrm{d}i_L}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{L}(v_{C1} - v_{C2})\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}v_{C1}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{C_1}\left(\frac{v_{C1}}{R1} + i_L\right)\\
\frac{\mathrm{d}v_{C2}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{C_2}\left(\frac{v_{C2}}{R2} - i_L\right)
\end{gather}

But when I am trying to get a transient response of these equations using some numerical integration scheme like Runge-Kutta or implicit backward Euler, the solution blows up.

Only for an initial condition \$(0,0,0)\$ it is zero everywhere. Whenever I try to put the different initial conditions, let's say \$(0.5,1,1)\$ it blows up.

Am I using initial conditions the wrong way? How to choose them correctly? I understand that by saying that for example \$v_{C1} = 10\$, it means that \$i_L = 10/(1||1)\$. Or is it even true? What is then \$v_{C2}\$?

Comment: Simulate it in spice or some other transient package

Comment: The initial voltages on caps and currents through inductors are independent of each other.

Comment: which means that my equations are wrong but I cant see it. it is probably messing with this single current

Comment: When you say blow uo, please explain with a waveform. Zoom into the waveform of the values go to ranges above, say, 10 V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem might be that your cap currents don't follow your +/- convention.

Here I've drawn all of the +/- indicators and current arrows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTBJYW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The resulting KCL and KVL equations are:

$$
\begin{align}
C_1\frac{dv_{C_1}}{dt} + \frac{v_{C_1}}{R_1} + i_L &= 0 \\
C_2\frac{dv_{C_2}}{dt} + \frac{v_{C_2}}{R_2} &= i_L \\
L\frac{di_L}{dt} &= v_{C_1} - v_{C_2} \\
\end{align}
$$

Translating your equations back to KCL current equations I get:
$$
\begin{align}
i_{C_1} &= i_{R_1} + i_L \\
i_{C_2} &= i_{R_2} - i_L \\
\end{align}
$$
which means the current arrows look like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLjrPi.png)</sup>

Comment: I made corrections according to your suggestions and now it works perfectly. Next time I must be more precise. Thank you, it helped me